# screen.fill not showing background color

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've started to program a game but I don't know why the background screen color is not changing. It's simply black. What am I doing wrong?

```
import sys
import pygame

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

    screen.fill(bg_color)
    pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

I'm on a Windows machine and using VS Code.

Comment: You're not filling in your game loop. You only fill and update the screen when you exit the game loop. Indent your code inside the `while`-loop and it should work

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter  of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You must draw the background and update the display **in** the application loop rather than **after** the application loop:

```py
def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

    # INDENTATION

    #-->|

        screen.fill(bg_color)
        pygame.display.flip()
```